# Context doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring

I have very strange problem with spring context.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    File file = new File("/home/user/IdeaProjects/Refactor/src/spring-cfg.xml");
    System.out.println("Exist "+file.exists());
    System.out.println("Path "+file.getAbsoluteFile());

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Show on console:

```
Exist true
Path /home/user/IdeaProjects/Refactor/src/spring-cfg.xml

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [home/user/IdeaProjects/Refactor/src/spring-cfg.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [home/user/IdeaProjects/Refactor/src/spring-cfg.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to load it as if `/home/user/IdeaProjects/Refactor/src/spring-cfg.xml` is a resource on the classpath - it's not, it's just a regular file. Try using [`FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html) instead... or specify a genuine classpath resource, e.g. just `spring-cfg.xml` assuming that your `src` directory is in your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very strange. You are trying to read the context from a file that does not exist.

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, true to its name, does not use the path as an absolute one but it seeks in the classpath. You should use

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring-cfg.xml");
```

NOTE: this will read the file not from `src` but from the compiled classes (where it should have been copied to while compiling).

Answer (score 0):

The message from the exception is correct, `/home/user/IdeaProjects/Refactor/src/spring-cfg.xml` is not a classpath resource (looks like a regular path from your machine).

I would advise using: `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-cfg.xml")` as your config xml looks like being in your source folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work

```
ApplicationContext context = 
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:/home/user/IdeaProjects/Refactor/src/spring-cfg.xml");
```

You can find some helpful information here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/resources.html